# JavaScript async/await not awaiting properly?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm having an issue with JavaScript's async/await functions.  This is happening on an internal application that I can't share the source for, but I put together a quick generic reproduction of my issue:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function baz(input) {
  console.log("4");
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("5");
  return input;
}

async function bar(input) {
  console.log("3");
  return await baz(input);
}

async function foo() {
  console.log("2");
  const foo = await bar("foo");
  return foo;
}

console.log("1");
foo();
console.log("6");
```

I would expect this to return the following with a one second wait between `4` and `5`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
"foo"
```

Instead, after trying this in the console in Chrome 64.0.3282.167 and Firefox 58.0.2 I receive this:

```
1
2
3
4
6
undefined
5
```

Please can someone point out where I'm going wrong in this?

Comment: you haven't awaited your call to `foo`.

Comment: You're right there, but that still doesn't explain why foo() is returning `undefined` and not `"foo"`.

Comment: its because you broke the underlying promise chain.

Comment: how can you expect `"foo"` to be output to the console? which line of your code do you think outputs that? all your console.log's are numeric, not once do you `console.log('foo')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The top-level is running synchronously (as it always does) - it doesn't wait for `foo();` to resolve before continuing to `console.log("6");`. Wrap the calling of `foo` in something async and `await` it. You also need to save the return value of `foo` if you want to display its later:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function baz(input) {
  console.log("4");
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("5");
  return input;
}

async function bar(input) {
  console.log("3");
  return await baz(input);
}

async function foo() {
  console.log("2");
  const foo = await bar("foo");
  return foo;
}

(async () => {
  console.log("1");
  const str = await foo();
  console.log("6");
  console.log(str);
})();
```

Comment: Right, but that doesn't explain why it's returning `undefined` rather than `foo`.

Comment: `undefined` is the "result" of the last `console.log` ... type `console.log('hello')` in the develoepr tools console ... oputput is `hello` and `undefined`

Comment: It turns out the example I gave doesn't accurately reproduce the issue I'm having.  I'm going to repost this question once I've created an accurate reproduction.  Since the answer you provided does answer the asked question and may help people in the future, I'm going to go ahead and mark it as the answer.

Thanks!